# $\tan2x$ in terms of $\cos x$ alone

Tags: trigonometry

This is not exactly a homework question but something I was trying to do to get my basics back on track.

I wanted to find $\tan2x$ in terms of $\cos x$ alone. I was able to do it in terms of $\sin x$ alone.

$\tan2x = \sin2x/\cos2x$

Since, $\cos2x = 1-2\sin^2x$

Therefore, $\tan2x = (\sin2x / 1-2\sin^2x)$

Is it possible to do it in terms of $\cos x$ alone ?

Comment: Note that $\cos 2x = 1 - 2\sin^2x$ not $1 - \sin^2x$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Yes, Sorry ! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, but only using care. It's not restrictive to assume $x\in[0,2\pi]$, because $\tan2x$ has $2\pi$ as period. Then you have
$$
\tan2x=
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{2\cos x\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}}{2\cos^2-1} &
  x\in[0,\pi]\\[2ex]
-\dfrac{2\cos x\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}}{2\cos^2-1} & 
  x\in[\pi,2\pi]
\end{cases}
$$
(the values $\pi/4$, $3\pi/4$, $5\pi/4$ and $7\pi/4$ are excluded, of course).

In other words, you can only express $|\tan2x|$ in terms of $\cos x$ alone.

Comment: your answer is more complete than my. +1

Comment: This assumes that you can ask whether $x$ is in one interval or another. But you can't do that when all we know about $x$ is its cosine,.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Of course. So what? The information would be insufficient, which means you *can't* express $\tan2x$ in terms of $\cos x$ only.

Comment: So your answer is not an answer. The question is to determine $\tan 2x$ given only $\cos x$. Your answer requires information that the question says we don't have.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Can you walk to the moon? I guess you can't. If the tools you have don't allow for getting an answer, the answer can't be obtained.

Answer (score 5):

$$\tan2x = \frac{\sin2x}{\cos2x}=\pm\frac{2\sin x\cos x}{\cos^2x-\sin^2x}=\pm\frac{2\cos x\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}}{2\cos^2x-1}$$

Comment: Are the square roots necessary? :)

Comment: @KartikAnand. Yes.

Comment: I meant is there are solution without square roots?

Comment: If $x=-\pi/6$, then $\tan2x=-\tan(\pi/3)=-\sqrt{3}$, while the expression on the right is $\sqrt{3}$. So your relation is false.

Comment: $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1\Rightarrow\sin x=\pm\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}$

Comment: The $\pm$ is of course meaningless.

Comment: Is from your opinion formula for solving quadratic equation $x_{1,2}=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$ meaningless?

Comment: $\tan 2x$ has a unique value; you have to tell which one to choose, or the formula means nothing.

Comment: That I left for you.

Comment: @egreg: Knowing $\cos x$ itself determines $x$ only up to its sign, so the $\pm$ is essential. There will be two different possible values of $\tan 2x$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Of which *only one* is correct.

Comment: @egreg: How do you propose to distinguish between them?

Comment: @HenningMakholm I did in my answer.

Comment: @egreg: Only by assuming that you know $x$ which you don't. (If you knew $x$ you could just ignore the $\cos x$ and compute $\tan 2x$ directly).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to do it without radicals, BUT only if you relax the demands of the problem to include $\cos(x+\phi)$ as well:

$$\tan2x=\frac{\sin2x}{\cos2x}=\frac{2\sin x\cos x}{\cos^2x-\sin^2x}=\frac{2\cos x\cos(x-\frac\pi2)}{2\cos^2x-1}$$

This way, you can also forget about worrying about signs! :-)